# Definition of adjoint functor similar to the definition of homotopy equivalence?

Tags: category-theory, definition, intuition

I am new at category theory and I haven't get the definition of adjoint functor. I have seen the [another definition of natural transformation much similar to the definition of homotopy.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/64365/48041)

[Other question in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438697/53976) gives the correlation between the basic concepts between topology and category, and it says that the adjoint functor is related to the homotopy equivalence. Thus I guess there is a definition of adjoint functor similar to the definition of homotopy equivalence, but I didn't get it.

[Counit-unit adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors#Counit-unit_adjunction) seems to give most close definition of adjoint functor I wanted, but I fail to find the direct relation between the counit-unit adjunction and the homotopy equivalence.

So my question is: there is a definition of adjoint functor resembles to the definition of homotopy equivalence, as like the question in MathOverflow I mentioned as a link? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Think of the adjoint functors as continuous functions and the unit and the counit as homotopies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept of [**adjunction**](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjunction) is essentially a feature of [2-categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category). Given a 2-category $\mathsf{C}$, two 1-morphisms $u : A \to B$ and $f : B \to A$ in $\mathsf{C}$ are said to be adjoint (denoted $u \dashv f$) when there exist 2-morphisms, the unit $\eta : \operatorname{id}_B \Rightarrow uf$ and the counit $\epsilon : fu \Rightarrow \operatorname{id}_A$ satisfying the usual triangle relations (that I won't write down here). Two adjoint functors are in some sense "dual" to each other. Both adjunction of categories are homotopy equivalences are special cases of this general notion of adjunction:

- Let $\mathsf{Cat}$ be the 2-category whose objects are categories, 1-morphisms are functors, and 2-morphisms are natural transformations. Then an adjunction as defined above is exactly the usual notion of [adjunction between two functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors).
- Let $\mathsf{Top}$ be the 2-category<sup>*</sup> whose objects are topological spaces, 1-morphisms are continuous maps, and 2-morphisms are homotopies. More precisely, given two continuous maps $f,g : X \to Y$, a 2-morphism $\alpha : f \Rightarrow g$ is a continuous map $\alpha : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that $\alpha(-,0) = f$ and $\alpha(-,1) = g$. Then every homotopy equivalence yields an adjunction in $\mathsf{Top}$.

The analogy is, however, not perfect: in $\mathsf{Top}$, every adjunction is in fact something stronger, an adjoint *equivalence*: the unit and the counit are invertible (like every 2-cell in $\mathsf{Top}$, in fact), which is not the case in $\mathsf{Cat}$.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is not a *strict* 2-category, as vertical 2-cell composition is not strictly associative, but this is not really important here for the intuition.